# Organize a C# model in a JSON

Tags: c#, sql

I have a model which I extract from a table in SQL like this:

```
{
    name: john,
    last name: dereck ,
    address: Av. Rider,
    country: USA.
}
```

How can I play with the information obtained in the table so that when it shows the JSON it paints it as follows:

```
{
    name: john,
    lastname: dereck ,
    location: {
             address: Av. Rider,
             country: USA.
    }
}
```

I keep the data in a list and work with C#.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json to serialize objects. It will serialize based on the model you provide.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var jsonObject = new JsonObjectDto
{
    Name = "john",
    LastName = "dereck",
    LocationDto = new LocationDto
    {
        Address = "Av. Rider",
        Country = "USA."
    }
};

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
```

Where the models/dtos look something like

```
public class JsonObjectDto
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("location")]
    public LocationDto LocationDto { get; set; }
}

public class LocationDto
{
    [JsonProperty("Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the answer works but if I had these fields in a table in sql, how would the modeling be?